# Generic factory typings

Tags: typescript, design-patterns, factory

There is simple factory and I don't understand why typescript produces error at main function `createFeature`.

How would be proper to describe types?

```js
interface Feature {
    id: string;
    kind: string;
}

export function create<Kind extends string, Fields extends Record<any, any>>(
  kind: Kind,
  options: Fields,
): Feature & { kind: Kind } & Fields {
  return {
    id: '',
    kind,
    ...options,
  };
}

interface PointOptions {
    coordinate: [number, number];
}

interface Point extends Feature {
    x: number;
    y: number;
}

function createPoint({ coordinate: [x, y] }: PointOptions): Point {
    return create('point', { x, y });
}

interface LineOptions {
    waypoints: [number, number][];
}

interface Line extends Feature {
    coordinates: { x: number; y: number }[];
}

function createLine(options: LineOptions): Line {
    return create('line', {
        coordinates: options.waypoints.map(([x, y]) => ({ x, y })),
    });
}

const features = {
    point: createPoint,
    line: createLine,
} as const;

type Library = typeof features;
export type FeatureKey = keyof Library;
export type FeatureOptions<Type extends FeatureKey> = Library[Type] extends (
  options: infer Options,
) => any
  ? Options
  : never;
export type FeatureReturn<Type extends FeatureKey> = Library[Type] extends (
  options: any,
) => infer ConcreteFeature
  ? ConcreteFeature
  : never;

function createFeature<Type extends FeatureKey>(
  type: Type,
  options: FeatureOptions<Type>,
): FeatureReturn<Type> {
  if (!(type in features)) {
    throw new Error('Unknown feature type');
  }
  return features[type](options);
}
```

Errors

```
Type 'Point | Line' is not assignable to type 'FeatureReturn<Type>'.
  Type 'Point' is not assignable to type 'FeatureReturn<Type>'.

Argument of type 'FeatureOptions<Type>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'PointOptions & LineOptions'.
  Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'PointOptions & LineOptions'.
    Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'PointOptions'.
      Type 'FeatureOptions<Type>' is not assignable to type 'PointOptions'.
        Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'PointOptions'.
```

[Code snippet](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGITmArlFBvAKGWOWABMAuZAZzClAHMBuIkga1EprsZYF8CBCAA8ADgHsoYZDCwgEYYOJDIEuTBAA8AaU7IRkEGWrd6IBgBo0wCABtj+4YYcAlCAkllNcEAE8rPr4AfEEAFKwcRlS6Rhas4qKKytRUqDb21HEAlKkY2LjIAGTIeMiRXDFkyHxF1nYOhMS4+SqNJORUAOSdcSRlnL0kAHQjCUkgmax8-IKgkLCIKAAK4nMA8olKEyWsxB6eoBpUANogWAC2AEbQVmdX0AC6MwRz0PBIyCtzjs4m6Jg4fC7ZDCKh3a5QFh9Xxgi4Q56yeTjVTqSBfcChUr7KBkQ6QE7CKy+B7VKjosAbcbUHKfVbgHZ9Zo4FRqPIQUKdCRzHolEFE6pZZ6vBYfAAyoAglK2JjaxAA7nBfFzwClkKc4TdkODHscngQBC9wG9FshxSAUAYIEY-nlAQySNjcSANKrSqCtRrIcgYR77lBqrqEXIFFsUWyzeyxtKqBGpckaRH7U0IC0wxoObYJTzZX1VOIDs7IKqo8khgqlXSwNQhuc4KJQqFjoTvQ8ssgALxBZCYvnegVZQbEPiC-WCDwTaQwW24EztpPIZVgKisjTkwfITPm5eoiARuI1OAmce0FgEMBKlDiy5QOBQXwd5Dn0QQcQwGTTiDUFgiCRSR8XtAP20CB7znNgQNfU1gGvW9fG-MRJGkJ8UH+fJJU2ZJNAAFQAy1rUAgFcGA4IHyvG872OHDnxJPCHHCYgSwmKhQCnf04wmbIOy7QJWAAfmQdjqFYMEIAAN2geDfyQgDUMBNwWmw3CnCtBxZKIkCuznMjYMoi8aOU-D6OQRjVUCTjO1IEBWOQABhZRWUgNSID42z7OaCAnOErUxIkwRERDZQ00cj9FOfH4VJtQiIGIsJWGQqgqIgQYTNyKLBNCiAgmyVK0Pk5kMq7NpgDfUIAEJQmQyz3yi6k2xzMAAAsoHEOVvNagBRKBmqgDkAFUQDYEAWpUKcov-Z9OhHIdWCZKARo-ahjmQh5QhMkc+CAA)

Comment: Please add the code to your question

Comment: @AluanHaddad There is link to code snippet

Comment: The code needs to be in the question directly as plaintext. A link to a web IDE is a nice supplement but it does not suffice. Please [edit] it in. I would do it myself, but there’s a weird copyright gray area where it isn’t clear if anyone but you is allowed to do so.  Once you do that, does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/W47YBm) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining what's going on; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz yep, your code is right what I need. Could you explain why my code produces error?

Comment: Is it possible to code without copy of `features` object?

Comment: It's not a copy of the object, it's a different reference to the same object. What is more important to you, suppressing the errors or getting the compiler to verify the type safety of what you're doing?  The change of variables is the most straightforward way to do the latter.  I am going to write up an answer but I'm not going to worry about trying to do it with a single `features` reference since that would end up sacrificing the type safety the solution is providing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for something like `features[type](options)` to type check, the compiler needs to understand that `features[type]` is a single function type that accepts a single argument of the same type as `typeof options`.  In your code, `feature[type]` is seen as a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) into `typeof features`, but the compiler doesn't see any single type it can assign to it.  So it ends up being widened to the [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) `((o: PointOptions) => Point) | ((o: LineOptions) => Line)` which cannot be safely called unless its input is *both* a `PointOptions` *and* a `LineOptions`.  But that's not what `typeof options` is, so it fails.  This is essentially a failure of TypeScript to directly support what I've been calling "correlated unions", as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).  If `feature[type]` is a union, then so is `options`, and these unions are *correlated* and not independent.  But the compiler fails to see it.

Luckily there is an approach that can lead the compiler to see the code as type safe, and it's described in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).  The idea is to represent everything in terms of some basic key-value interface types, or [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over them, and then do generic indexes into these types.  This is actually somewhat close to what you're doing already, with the major exception that `features` itself is not written as a mapped type.  Here's are the fixes you need:

First, we should rename `features` out of the way so that we can later change its apparent type to a more compiler-friendly version:

```
const _features = {
  point: createPoint,
  line: createLine,
} as const;

type Library = typeof _features;
```

Then, your `FeatureOptions` and `FeatureReturn` types can be rewritten as full object types with the same keys as `typeof _features`:

```
type FeatureKey = keyof Library;

type FeatureOptions = { [K in FeatureKey]: Library[K] extends (
  options: infer O) => any ? O : never; }

type FeatureReturn = { [K in FeatureKey]: Library[K] extends (
  options: any) => infer R ? R : never; }
```

And finally, we write `features` as a mapped type that explicitly relates `FeatureOptions` to `FeatureReturn`:

```
const features: { [K in FeatureKey]:
  (options: FeatureOptions[K]) => FeatureReturn[K] } = _features;
```

All of this looks like a big no-op, since the old type of `features` and the new type are equivalent.  But the compiler does not see them as identical.  The compiler cannot "see" the abstraction over `K` for the first version.  For the new version, now the compiler will understand that `features[type]` will be of type `(options: FeatureOptions[K]) => FeatureReturn[K]` if `type` is of type `K`, and thus it's a single function type that can be called.

Like this:

```
function createFeature<K extends FeatureKey>(
  type: K,
  options: FeatureOptions[K],
): FeatureReturn[K] {
  return features[type](options); // okay
}
```

Again, it's not like your original version was *wrong*, it's just that the compiler didn't understand what you were doing.  For more information about the general issue and the approach taken here, please see the GitHub issues linked above.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGITmArlFBvAKGWWABMAuZAZzClAHMBuI5Aa1AutoeYF8CCMLCARhgAexDIEuTBAA8AaWQQAHpBCkqXOiHoAaNCvURN28QCMAVhFEA+ABQt2myov0txABzGSqlVA8ASgCMbFxkADJkPDYON2ReKKNCYlxwqVTiEk4AclyPbLjNQuyAOgrvXxAqUt4+AVBIWEQUAAVxJoB5HwkamJYEcXEoUlA5SgBtECwAWwtoQxn56ABdBoIm6HgkZA6m4w0tNDCcfBZVSmWFqGZiAE8ruZuNoRFq6VlIffAHWKGRmMQBNkJNVIZ7qtEpQfmAetUqCE9p1wAM0hAMp8whAHLkvCiwAUYshwch7okghsti1dgAZUAQeF9bRZADucHu+Ka-lB10WyD5UFWk3WBH4m3A21ayHpIBQaiO2nQmDOaOkw1G40gPNilwFz2gjDJTxWUESItewlEfSxcllOKqzMo9qZfiR9rV6RwUhk2NxABsGUSssQAZrgdrKI6-GV2ZyCVQyrM4F4HA4wRDVkFkABeOzIP4kiEUoJ1SligRDGpgZAAfRgp1w2hzaq54EovrksNKgblHa+EHtHiScG0VZozAIYE5KHpFigcCg5Jb068EHEMDrDZVTeYq5QyvCEEUEGXbFPG5lwHni-uk-3Jx3jN6flzxMmylAj6PJ8hzuvC5Lh+UIKqYxxOMQ0Y1JQoANmaXTZnmyBwCA5IAPzIF0yBXBAABuhqJAID6HmcABKGLem+sQfiQUgkbgv6rP+N5AYoIEmGYBaeC+0HIahiH5rB0DIKRyAYaJOH4bchEEOONbbkeOqgp+dGNsep5MSwDhQTy9HPgiwECd+ZEUVAIDAYkb71mpVCToIVofJ2kB6UohxgUqam-o4LD7m4pQ6aET6ujUwHBIFR7kRkFlZF6ZnIApZxUJM+6rNpPGInwQA)